# Redux How to insert new Sub data in state

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, redux

I'm making a todo app and using redux for state management. My todo state is made up of nested arrays.

```
const initialState = {
  todos: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "task1",
      subdata: [
        {
          id: 101,
          name: "subtask1",
          complete: false,
        },
        {
          id: 102,
          name: "subtask2",
          complete: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "task2",
      subdata: [
        {
          id: 103,
          name: "subtask3",
          complete: false,
        },
        {
          id: 104,
          name: "subtask4",
          complete: true,
        },
      ],
    },
```

Reducers:

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      const newTodo = state.todos.concat(action.payload);
      return { ...state, todos: newTodo };

    case ADD_SUBTODO:
      const newSubtodo = action.payload;
?????????????????????????????????????????????
```

How can i append new subtodo to initialstate?
I used the immer library, but I want to do it the traditional way, for example the spread operator. I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like...

```
// send payload as {id:1,newSubtodo: newSubtodo} 
case ADD_SUBTODO:
      const newSubtodo = action.payload.newSubtodo;
      //id is the task/todo id of which you want to add a new subdata
      const newTask = initialState.todos.find(i=>i.id==action.payload.id) 
      //id is the task/todo id of which you want to add a new subdata
      newTask.subdata.push(newSubtodo) 
      return {...initialState,todos:[...initialState.todos,newTask]}
```

> Note: Using nested objects as state in React Js is not a good
> practice.